# How to interpret Diagnostics and Data?

Tags: iphone, history, macos

I am trying to understand what all this means.  This is one of the many different files in `Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostic & Usage Data` that I have found on my phone. If someone can please explain what some of this means, I would appreciate it.

```
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1468646908501
  triggerId: 1245186
  profileId: 890352
  pushConnectionDisconnected {
    timestamp: 1468646908501
    connectionType: 2
    linkQuality: 100
    error: 2
    genericError: 0
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1468646908502
  triggerId: 1245186
  profileId: 890352
  pushConnectionDisconnected {
    timestamp: 1468646908502
    connectionType: 2
    linkQuality: 100
    error: 2
    genericError: 0
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1468647720295
  triggerId: 589833
  profileId: 890366
  wiFiMetricLinkChangeData {
    timestamp: 1468647720293
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    rssiHistory: 1090477
    isLinkUp: false
    isInVol: true
    reason: 1
    subreason: 7
    channel: 0
    channelWidth: 0
    phyMode: 0
    flags: 0
    oui: [3 bytes] 00 00 00
    securityType: 0
    wpaProtocol: 0
    mcastCipher: 0
    ucastCipher: 0
    akmSuites: 0
    capabilities: 0
    htInfo: 0
    htExtended: 0
    htTxBf: 0
    htASel: 0
    htAmpduParams: 0
    htSupportedMcsSet: [16 bytes] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    vhtInfo: 0
    vhtSupportedMcsSet: [8 bytes] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    txPerHistory: 0
    txPerHistory: 0
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txPerHistory: 50
    txFrmsHistory: 0
    txFrmsHistory: 0
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    txFrmsHistory: 4
    fwTxPerHistory: 0
    fwTxPerHistory: 0
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxPerHistory: 50
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 0
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 0
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    fwTxFrmsHistory: 27
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnPerHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    bcnFrmsHistory: 0
    gatewayARPHistory: 0
  }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was put on hold. Edith posted a log file she found on her phone and wants to know what the content means. What is unclear about that?

Comment: Basically it was just a wall of unformatted text. Even with that being fixed, its still unclear where the file is coming from, so at least a path/filename (or how to access it through Settings or similar) would help.

Comment: @patrix Cool. Added the path to the files in Settings.